# GradientStop Animation for TextBlock.Foreground not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, binding

I have a TextBlock in which I would like to animate a LinearGradient for the foreground in certain situations.  In other situations the color needs to be a simple solid color.  I have been able to get the Gradient Animation to work, but ONLY if no foreground color is set.

XAML

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="AlarmTextBrush" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad">
     <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"  />
     <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".5" />                        
</LinearGradientBrush>

<TextBlock FontWeight="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource BoldConverter}, IsAsync=True}"  Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, IsAsync=True}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource TextColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=Label, IsAsync=True}">                                
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>     
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="true">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <conv:IsBlinkingStatusConverter />
                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="True" />
                            <Binding Path="IsAcknowledged" IsAsync="True" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AlarmTextBrush}" />
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="RollingGradientText">
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" From=".2" To="1.5" By=".1" Duration="0:0:3"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" From="1" To="1.5" By=".1" Duration="0:0:3"/>                                                           
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RollingGradientText" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger> 
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

If I remove the foreground attribute from TextBlock this works.  If I leave the binding or even just set it to White it will error.  I need to be able to set the foreground different and still have the animation work.  Its almost as though the animation is trying to fire before its finished resolving the GradientBrush instead of the SolidColorBrush.

Comment: I dont know the solution but your problem lies here : `(TextBlock.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)` or `(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)`

Comment: @Vishal Right, what I can't figure out is why it Works for Rectangle.Fill but doesn't for TextBlock.Foreground?

Comment: @jrandomuser is it that you're returning a gradient brush with more gradient stops than what you defined in your storyboard?

Comment: also notice that you have a separate converter explicitly used for `Rectange.Fill`, do you need to do the same with `TextBlock.Foreground`?

Comment: @NETscape I removed one of the stops just to be sure.  I also used a separate converter with the same results.  If I remove the Storyboard the text will render with the Gradient just fine.  It only blows up with the animations.  It seems like it is trying to say it can't access that property path but I can't understand whats wrong with it.